# rails model templates (or instance inheritance) options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, prototype

I have a situation where I want to make 'parametric' models in rails; for example I'd like to define `PrototypeRecipe`, and then be able to make multiple `DerivedRecipe`'s; maybe one derived recipe uses more sugar and another uses less eggs or something.  The critical point is that I want all the 'derived' instances to inherit properties from a single shared `PrototypeRecipe`, but be able to make local modifications.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to define methods on the prototype (say, putting together a shopping list), and have these methods respond to local changes in derived instances (so if I specified 3 eggs instead of 2, i could call the prototype's `make_shopping_list` function and it would reflect that).

Is there an existing method for accomplishing something like this?  Here's the best I can come up with so far:

```
class Ingredient << ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :recipe, :polymorphic => true

    # uuid => UUID String (for grouping ingredients which change between prototype and derived instances)
end

class PrototypeRecipe << ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :ingredients

    def make_ingredient_list(derived_recipe = nil)
        self.ingredients.map {|i| derived_recipe.nil? ? i : derived_recipe.ingredients.where(:ingredient_uuid => i.uuid).first }
    end
end

class DerivedRecipe << ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :prototype_recipe

    has_many :ingredients

    def method_missing(sym, *args)
        self.prototype_recipe.send( sym, *args, self)
    end
end
```

I know this code can be made a lot cleaner, I'm more wondering if the general approach can be improved on.  The basic idea is that ingredients would each have a unique ID.  To modify a prototype recipe, you simply create an instance of `DerivedRecipe`, link it to the prototype, and then add an ingredient with the same UUID as one of the prototype's ingredients.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on what behavior you are looking to have, so here's my attempted solution.

Single-Table Inheritance (STI). Your base class will be `PrototypeRecipe` and your child class will be `DerivedRecipe`.

In your `prototype_recipes` table, specify a `type` column (text). This signals to Rails you want to use STI. If you put your `make_ingredients_list` method inside the base class, it will be accessible from your child classes.

```
# app/models/ingredient.rb
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe, :class_name => "PrototypeRecipe"
  ...
end

# app/models/prototype_recipe.rb
class PrototypeRecipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ingredients
  has_many :derived_recipes

  def make_ingredient_list
    ...
  end
end

# app/models/derived_recipe.rb
class DerivedRecipe < PrototypeRecipe
  belongs_to :prototype_recipe
end
```

Now you can do something like:

```
@cupcakes = PrototypeRecipe.create
@cupcakes_with_extra_eggs = @cupcakes.derived_recipes.create
print @cupcakes_with_extra_eggs.make_ingredient_list
```

Is this what you were looking for?